# How to save a list of dataframes while producing them iteratively?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, iteration, pickle

I have a lot of folders, from which I am generating different dataframes, according to some criteria. 
As a result, the loop produces one dataframe each iteration. I want to save all of them in different .plk files. 
I'm just using it:

```
df.to_pickle('df')
```

But it only saves the last one. I need something like:

```
df.to_pickle(df[i].plk')
```

Where `i` is for each iteration.

Comment: Please give more detail on the data being used and expected results. It's difficult with just the information given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace your this line

```
df.to_pickle(df[i].plk')
```

with

```
df.to_pickle(f"df_{i}".plk)
```

it will save your files on df_1.plk, df_2.plk, df_3.plk etc

Answer (score 4):

This is how I manage:
First create an empty list where you will append each dataframe you create:

```
df_appender = []
```

Suppose I generate a list `ids` that contains unique values that will be used to iterate and generate each dataframe you desire:

```
ids = ['A','B','C','D','E']
```

Here is where the loop takes place and whatever logic you want to apply to create new dataframes and append them:

```
for i in range(len(ids)):
    dfx = df[df['id'] == ids[i]] 
    dfx = dfx.sort_values(['day'],ascending=[True])
    dfx = dfx.drop_duplicates(['day'],keep='last')
    df_appender.append(dfx)
    print(i/len(ids))
```

Now you have a list with dataframes for each iteration, finally if you want to concatenate them to one big dataframe you can do:

```
final_df = pd.concat(df_appender,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, man. I've upvoted the above comment since it is simpler than yours. Anyway, I appreciate your time and effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of contribution, I did it, and it has worked:

```
df[i].to_pickle(str(i)+'some_name.plk')
```